# Using replace() on decoded URI hex codes with native division operator

Tags: javascript, regex

Building a calculator.

```
var process = "6÷6";  // need to replace division sign with one that javascript can evaluate with
process = encodeURI(process);
process.replace(/%C3%B7/gi,'/'); // replacement step that doesn't work - %C3%B7 is what shows up as the hex divison sign in chrome debugger, not sure why
process = decodeURI(process);
result = eval(process);
```

Comment: works for me. Chrome 50.0 and Safari 9.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third line of your code is wrong. You have to assign the return value of the replace function to a variable. The easiest way is to assign it to itself:

```
process = process.replace(/%C3%B7/gi,'/');
```

So the whole script code would look like this:

```
var process = "6÷6";  // need to replace division sign with one that javascript can evaluate with
process = encodeURI(process);
process = process.replace(/%C3%B7/gi,'/'); // replacement step now works
process = decodeURI(process);
result = eval(process);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create an object with properties set to arithmetic operators. Note, `.replace()` may not be necessary

```js
var map = {"÷":"/"};
var operatorType = "÷";
var process = "6" + map[operatorType] + "6";  // need to replace division sign with one that javascript can evaluate with
process = encodeURI(process);
process.replace(/%C3%B7/gi,'/'); // replacement step that doesn't work - %C3%B7 is what shows up as the hex divison sign in chrome debugger, not sure why
process = decodeURI(process);
result = eval(process);
document.body.innerHTML = result;
```